# Minus the value based on data using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've the following data.

[image]

What I need like below

[image]

I need to minus order by 1 with 2.

Example : (1-2) and I've display the result in order by 3.

If the branch having order_by as 1 - display as it is.

Using MySQL, how can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this result with a `UNION` query. The first part selects all rows from your table, the second uses a self-join to find branches which have `order_by` values of both 1 and 2, and subtracts their `due` values to get the new `due` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, d1.branch, d1.due - d2.due
FROM data d1
JOIN data d2 ON d2.branch = d1.branch AND d2.order_by = 2
WHERE d1.order_by = 1
ORDER BY branch, order_by
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qQUYyfiS52ACavYqGq1ZQ9/0)

Comment: Thanks Bro. Working fine for me.

Comment: Doubt : For order_by 1, i've different query and For order_by 2, i've different query. i UNION ALL both the queries and i got this result. I don't know how to include my existing code in it.

Comment: @Phoenix you would need to `UNION ALL` the `order_by 1` query, then `order_by 2` query, then the `JOIN` of the `order_by 1` query and the `order_by 2` query. I see you're using MariaDB, if you're using version 10.2.1 or later you could use CTEs to make this easier.